# Struggling to understand how to correctly allocate memory using malloc()

Tags: c, arrays, malloc

Apologies if this seems like a re-post of a question I asked previously. I have an array of data, `arr`, and an array of indexes, `index`. My goal is to use a for loop to create new arrays of data partitioned at each of the indexes and to further find the minimum in each partitioned array. I am using `malloc` to create a dynamic array which I then free at the end of each loop.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

 int main(void)
 {
     int j;
     int arr[] = {1,3,4,6,7,8,12,87,89,12,34,43,54,67,81,2,0,10,23,45,81,23,89,23,56,81,28,79};
     int index[] = {1,5,10,13,19,24};
     int h = 27;
     int k;
     int c;
     int len;
     for(j = 0;j < 4;++j)
     {   printf("\n");
         len = index[j+1] - index[j] - 1;
         printf("len %d: ",len);
         int *temp_arr = malloc(1000*sizeof(int));
         for(k = index[j];k<(index[j+1]);++k )
         {
             printf("array val %d, ", arr[k]);
             temp_arr[k] = arr[k];
         }
         int local_min ;
         local_min = temp_arr[0];
         for ( c = 1 ; c < len ; c++ )
         {    printf("Temp array %d, ", temp_arr[c]);
             if ( temp_arr[c] < local_min)
             {
                 local_min = temp_arr[c];
                 printf("Local min in loop %d ", local_min );
             }
         }
         free(temp_arr);
         printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
 }
```

I do not understand how to correctly allocate the memory using `malloc`. I have been experimenting with different values; Too small a value and my program crashes, too large a value and *some* of my output is non-sensible. In the example I have given here, I get a mixture of correct values and nonsense values.

Is there an issue with creating this dynamic array for each `j` value? Am I correctly de-allocating  the memory using `free(temp_arr)`?

Comment: "*Is there an issue with creating this dynamic array for each `j` value?*" (besides being somewhat inefficient doing this over and over again) no, "*Am I correctly de-allocating  the memory using `free(temp_arr)`?*" yes.

Comment: You need to ensure that `k` and `c`, or any index you use to access `temp_arr`, is less than its length.

Comment: @alk, can you suggest how I can do this more efficiently? I am very new to C

Comment: @meowgoesthedog, thanks for the explanation. I had not thought of that

Comment: "*more efficiently*" just have the memory for the `int`s be allocated on the stack by doing `int temp_arr[1000];`.

Comment: My understanding was that I would not be able to delete a static array? I would need to delete the array at each loop iteration to find the new array minium

Comment: You need to know how many elements you want. Once you know that, malloc is simple: `malloc(n_elements_you_want * sizeof(Element)`. If you don't know how many elements yoi want, asking  "how to use malloc" would be a bit premature.

Comment: If you want to do this more efficiently, ditch the temporary array - you should be able to work out `local_min` with just one loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are allocating 1000 `ints` in every loop and then freeing. Again and again.

If you want same size everytime you can move mallocing and freeing out of loop, and even better, use automatic array.

```
int temp_arr[1000] = { 0, };   // Iam automatic array
```

But if you want adapt size of malloced array to how many `int`s you actually need in every loop, leave mallocing where it is and instead of `1000`, calculate real size, which is in variable `len`.

```
int *temp_arr = malloc(len *sizeof(int));
```

---

You have to modify this snippet of code as well, becouse you are filling `temp_arr` from `index[j]` to `index[j+1]` (it could be `13` to `19`), and you are accessing it from index `0`. It is undefined behavior since values there may be uninitialized.

```
for(k = index[j];k<(index[j+1]);++k )
{
    printf("array val %d, ", arr[k]);
    temp_arr[k] = arr[k];
}
```

to

```
int indexCounter = 0;
for(k = index[j];k<(index[j+1]);++k )
{
    printf("array val %d, ", arr[k]);
    temp_arr[indexCounter++] = arr[k];
}
```

After mallocing modification, when your array would have only `len` bounds (i.e. about `5`), you would access outside of bounds and it would lead to UB as well.

**[Here is live demo.](http://ideone.com/XKpUpT)**
With these modifications your code works well and is more effective (checked with valgrind).

Comment: That is a great explanation - thanks! I will also try to modify the code so that I can find the minimums without using free_temp, as suggested by @Chris Turner

Comment: @Sjoseph Thank you, iam glad it helped you. Yes it is possible, if you cant figure it out do not hesitate to ask ! Have a nice day.

Answer (score 3):

You are filling `temp_arr` from `index[j]` to `index[j+1]` and then you are printing its values from `c=1` to `c=len=index[j+1] - index[j] - 1`.

First: you are printing values you maybe haven't initialized yet because you are reading at places were you haven't write yet. It's an undefined behavior.

Second: you must ensure that `index[j]`, `index[j+1]`, and `len-1` are smaller or equal to the length of the array you allocated with malloc.